# Repositioning views on viewWillTransition

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have an app for iOS that has 3 container views (A, B & C). Top container view (A) which is static and one container view underneath (B) with a button that "moves" it to the side to reveal the third container view (C). The issue I am having is that when I move from B to C and then flip the phone sidways B & C are overlapped, they dont retain their positions and the positions are suddenly overlapped, if I press the move button, since they're both overlapped they both go out of screen. I've added 3 screenshots showing the behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P470.jpg

So far this is my setup on viewDidLoad I call resetPositions():

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController{
 var isMainContainer: Bool = true

func resetPositions() {
        if isMainContainer {
            if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
                containerViewBot.center.y = containedView.center.y
                containerViewBotBack.center.y = containedView.center.y - offset
            } else {
                containerViewBot.center.x = self.view.center.x
                containerViewBotBack.center.x = self.view.center.x - offset
            }
        } else {
            if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
                containerViewBotBack.center.y = containedView.center.y
                containerViewBot.center.y = containedView.center.y + offset
            } else {
                containerViewBotBack.center.x = self.view.center.x
                containerViewBot.center.x = self.view.center.x + offset
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the "isMainContainer" changes when I press the button to "move" from one view to the other:

```
func getMore(from: String) {
        //from is the sender
        if from == "homeResults" {
            containerViewBotBack.isHidden = false
            goToCommute()
        } else {
            //containerViewBotBack.isHidden = true
            containerViewBot.isHidden = false
            goToResults()
        }
    }
```

Finally the goToCommute and goToResults methods:

```
func goToCommute() {
    let duration = 0.5
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.moveUp(view: self.containerViewBot)
            self.moveUp(view: self.containerViewBotBack)
        }) { (_) in
            self.containerViewBotBack.isHidden = false
            self.containerViewBot.isHidden = true
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.moveRight(view: self.containerViewBot)
            self.moveRight(view: self.containerViewBotBack)
        }) { (_) in
            self.containerViewBotBack.isHidden = false
            self.containerViewBot.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    isMainContainer = false
}

func goToResults() {
    let duration = 0.5
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.moveDown(view: self.containerViewBot)
            self.moveDown(view: self.containerViewBotBack)
        }) { (_) in
            self.containerViewBot.isHidden = false
            self.containerViewBotBack.isHidden = true
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.moveLeft(view: self.containerViewBot)
            self.moveLeft(view: self.containerViewBotBack)
        }) { (_) in
            self.containerViewBot.isHidden = false
            self.containerViewBotBack.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    isMainContainer = true
}
```

I call the "resetPositions()" command on override viewWillTransition(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect device rotation by the following way and reposition your items.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceRotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

func deviceRotated(){
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Landscape")
        // Resize other things
    }
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Portrait")
        // Resize other things
    }
}
```

Comment: I already detect the rotation in the func override ViewWillTransition.

Comment: then what is your exact question or problem ?

Comment: the repositioning when the rotation happens overlays the container views instead of keeping them off with an offset